# Failing to create AWS EC2 instance sbin/plymouthd: No such file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

my ec2 instance is failing to continue running. It's being created and then terminated and that's the only error I see in the syslog:

```
/dev/fd/11: line 1: /sbin/plymouthd: No such file or directory
initctl: Event failed
Stopping atd: [  OK  ]
```

I'm using the latest AMI and searched everywhere and couldn't find a good answer for that. 
I deleted my scripts in the User-Data to make sure they are not the issue. 
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: |
          #!/bin/bash
          export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=@AWS::Region

```
      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v \
        --stack @AWS::StackName \
        --resource SmoketestInstance \
        --region @AWS::Region

      cd /smoketest
      #./smoke-test-setup.sh

      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 \
        --stack @AWS::StackName \
        --region @AWS::Region \
        --resource SmoketestInstance
```

I'm creating everything with cloud formation. And worths to mention that the same AMI is used for another stack and I even created an EC2 now with it just to check if it's working.
Any idea or suggestion how can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, the stack was being deleted and nothing went wrong. This line confused me but it's absolute fine.

Comment: @PraneethPeiris there was a command that deletes the stack and I didn't see it.  I was focusing the the (system log ).